# Почему не работает вывод сайта с Wayback Machine на указываемую дату?

Tags: python

В учебнике по программированию есть пример:

```
import webbrowser
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen

print("let's find an old website.")
site = input("type a website url: ")
era = input("type a year, month, and day like 20150613: ")
url = "http://archive.org/wayback/available?url=%s&timestamp=%s" % (site, era)
response = urlopen(url)
contents = response.read()
text = contents.decode("utf-8")
data = json.loads(text)
try:
    old_site = data["archived snapshots"]["closest"]["url"]
    print("found this copy: ", old_site)
    print("it should apper in your browser now.")
    webbrowser.open(old_site)
except:
    print("sorry, no luck finding", site)
```

он должен выводить в браузере скрин с сайта указанной даты(через api wayback machine)
но какую бы дату я не вводил, какой бы сайт я не указывал он выдаёт последний принт.

заходил на wayback machine и смотрел есть ли данные по сайту(указанной даты), даже когда они были, код выводил последний принт

Answer (score 0):

значит что-то происходит на строчках

```
old_site = data["archived snapshots"]["closest"]["url"]
webbrowser.open(old_site)
```

и срабатывает исключение

скорее всего вот на этой строчке

```
old_site = data["archived snapshots"]["closest"]["url"]
```

посмотрите вообще что у вас внутри `data` - может там нет таких полей, к которым вы обращаетесь

```
data = json.loads(text)
print(data)
```

от этого и пляшите

Comment: я добавил 

`data = json.loads(text)
print(data)`

он стал выводить в командной строке 

`url': 'lolcats.com', 'archived_snapshots': {}, 'timestamp': '20151022`
извините, я не понимаю как сделать так же красиво, как вы выделили код :(

Comment: я полагаю. он должен мне сразу открывать в браузере страницу с найденным скриншотом, без вывода в консоль

Comment: вот видите - у вас `'archived_snapshots'` - пустой словарь, т.е. в нем нет ключа `"closest"`, а вы по ключу обращаетесь, поэтому происходит исключение